# ScrollView React Native Horizontal Not Working

Tags: react-native, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am developing app with `RN 0.59.8`. I am trying to create scrollable view horizontally with `ScrollView`. Here is basis of my code (sorry I couldn't share more detail):

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
} from 'react-native';
import {
  Container,
  Content,
} from 'native-base';
import { Grid, Row } from 'react-native-easy-grid';

import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';

class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      data,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <Container>
        <Content>
          <Grid>
            <Row>
              <ScrollView
                horizontal
                contentContainerStyle={{
                  flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexDirection: 'row',
                }}
              >
                {
                  data.map((item, index) => {
                    const order = index;

                    return (
                      <Fragment key={order}>
                        {
                          <ChildComponent />
                        }
                      </Fragment>
                    );
                  })
                }
              </ScrollView>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </Content>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```

Current behavior:

1. if `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}`, the second data not appear
2. if `contentContainerStyle={{ flex: 1, flexGrow: 1, flexDirection:
   'column' }}`, the second data appear vertically
3. if `contentContainerStyle={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}`, the second data not appear and the content is wider than the screen width

My **objection** is:

1. I want to make it scrollable horizontally
2. Each data will fit the screen width

Any help would be very helpful. Thank you!!!

Comment: so you simply want to make every child of this scrollView the width of the screen? if so, you can change the way the children are rendered, add style to them and set their width to '100%'

Comment: @mAhMoUdDaFeR I've tried that but problem is still the second data not appear anywhere if I set flexDirection to 'row', but all data appear vertically if I set flexDirection to 'column'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Straight from React Native docs, for the scroll view's children to be arranged horizontally in a row instead of vertically in a column the only prop you need to use it's [`horizontal`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#horizontal).

```js
<ScrollView horizontal>
  <Child/>
</ScrollView>
```

I created a snack to show you, [@abranhe/stackoverflow-56721203](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-56721203):

[image]

to make it fit the screen width, play with your component and:

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

Dimensions.get('width').width
```

The demo source code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Image, ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import data from './data';

export default class App extends Component {
  renderCity(city) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cardContainer}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Image source={{ uri: city.img }} style={styles.image} />
          <Text style={styles.title}>{city.title}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView horizontal>
          {data.map(city => {
            return this.renderCity(city);
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    marginTop: 30,
  },
  title: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
  image: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200,
    borderRadius: 10,
    marginTop: 10,
  },
  cardContainer: {
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  card: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    margin: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 220,
  },
});
```

> **Keep in mind**

Some UI components from **native-base** have absolute values, you may change your theme variables, to make them fit your needs.

If you don't want to show your scroll indicator, you can set to `false` the [ScrollView's `showsHorizontalScrollIndicator`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#showshorizontalscrollindicator) prop.

Comment: after looking around, the problem is in styling of the child component. But, your answer above guided me to solve my problem. Thanks a lot for your complete answers. Have a nice day!